# case_when does not return correct case when checking for character(0)

Tags: r

I am mapping some values to different categories. Some of the values have character(0), which I want to map to 'Other'. But I cannot get it to return anything else than character(0). I have tried using different methods (using length(character(0) == 0 for example).

```
### Map code 1100 to House.
test_vec = '1100'
case_when(
  test_vec == '1100' ~ 'House'
)
#[1] House

### Map character(0) to Other
test_vec = character(0)
case_when(
  test_vec == '1100' ~ 'House',
  identical(test_vec, character(0)) ~ 'Other'
)
#Character(0)
```

Comment: Do you have length 1 vector always?

Comment: No, sometimes there is a length 0 vector, hence I want to test for the character(0).

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it comes from the test `test_vec == 1100`, which will throw a `logical(0)` instead of a TRUE/FALSE if `test_vec` is a `character(0)`.

One way to bypass could be to add a positive length condition on every test of `test_vec` value:

```r
test_vec = character(0)
case_when(
  length(test_vec) > 0 && test_vec == '1100' ~ 'House',
  identical(test_vec, character(0)) ~ 'Other'
)
```

> [1] "Other"

Comment: That makes sense, but oh no, oh no, why does it continue after getting a true condiction?! After reading your answer, I changed the code to: ```case_when(
  identical(test_vec, character(0)) ~ 'Other',
  test_vec == '1100' ~ invisible('success')
)``` which should work, as I expect it to stop after a true condition. BUT IT DOES NOT! It stil evaluates the next one, probably getting a `logical(0)` and returning `character(0)`. The only thing that works is ```case_when(
  identical(test_vec, character(0)) ~ 'Other'
)```, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: Your approach does not work, because `case_when` does not act like an `ifelse` or a loop. It evaluates all conditions (the "left side", or LHS) first. As stated in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when "documentation"):   

> > The LHS must evaluate to a logical VECTOR. <<

which means that ALL conditions must return a TRUE or a FALSE. The order of appearance will matter only if several conditions are TRUE. In this case, the first of them will throw the answer.

Comment: But it also states "Like an if statement, the arguments are evaluated in order, so you must proceed from the most specific to the most general.", so order matters sometimes? I am very confused. The LHS evaluates then to logical(0) and TRUE, why does it not choose the TRUE condition and return 'Other'? character(0) isn't a possible return value, so where does that come from? Is it because one of the LHS evaluates to logical(0), it just gives up and returns the input?

Comment: Yes, see my comment : the order matters, assumed that your logical is valid. Which is not the case if one value is character(0)

Comment: Yea, i've read your comment, but I'm just having a real difficulty understanding what is going on. I think my issue stems from that I don't understand why it cares that there is a logical(0), if there is a true statement before it. There is probably a very good reason for it, which I am not smart enough to undersand, but I understand better now how case_when works, so I thank you for your help!

Comment: Have in mind that R is a _vectorized_ language and that many operations are doing that way. Think of the "apply" functions family, vs a basic "for" loop in other languages.